# C# adding doubles ends with .000000001

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, double

Why does this code produce the correct answer, except for the .000000001 at the end?

I have a DataGridView, that in a column has prices. This code goes down the grid, gets the values and adds them up.

```
double pp = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < PPUTDG.RowCount; i++)
{
    try
    {
      pp = pp + Convert.ToDouble(PPUTDG[16, i].Value.ToString().Replace("$",""));
    }
    catch { }
}
```

I then call .ToString() on pp.
The values should add to 6240.75, except I get 6240.75000000001.

Thanks.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Try using `decimal` type instead.

Comment: Read up on this topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/what-is-the-difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-c

Comment: I thought that since the numbers weren't overly large, a double would be fine. Guess not. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a lot to be found about this. I already gave one, this: http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/ is another.

In short:

> "...internally, computers use a format (binary floating-point) that cannot accurately represent a number like 0.1, 0.2 or 0.3 at all."

Make sure you really need a floating point type. When dealing with money for example, it is better to use `decimal` or an integer and do your calculations in cents.

A good rule-of-thumb can be that it is OK to use a floating point type if the decimal-rounding errors are no problem in your application. Otherwise, use something else.

Comment: I like it when problems are so easily solved, thanks!
I'll accept your answer when the time limits up.

Answer (score 1):

For financial calculations use decimal type instead of double or float types.